# Jquery Referencing this

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Given the object:

```
// A data set
$.DataArea = function () {

    // Default options
    $.extend(this, {
        class: 'DataSet',
        data: new Array(),
        container: null
    });

    // Add a bar to this object
    this.addBar = function(startDate, endDate, label) {    
        var insertPos = this.data.length;
        this.data[insertPos] = new $.DataBar();
        this.data[insertPos].startDate = startDate;
        this.data[insertPos].endDate = endDate;
        this.data[insertPos].label = label;

        this.container.children('.jobArea').append('<div class="bar-wrapper"><div class="bar">' + label + '</div></div>');   



    }

    // Bind the bar to a div
    this.bind = function(docID) {
        this.container = $('#' + docID);   
        this.container.append('<div class="jobArea"></div>')     
    };

    this.init = function() {

        this.container.children('.jobArea .bar, .jobArea .marker').each(function(i) {
            $(i).bind("selectstart", _preventDefault);
        });

    };

};
```

The line `$(this).bind("selectstart", _preventDefault);` I think is not working, because `$(this)` is conflicting with the `this` of the object?

How can I correctly reference the selected element in the `each` loop in a non conflicting way? (If that's the problem)

**Edit**

DataArea in use:

```
var MyData = new $.DataArea();
MyData.bind("container");
MyData.addBar("", "", "Bar 1");
MyData.addBar("", "", "Bar 2");
MyData.init();
```

Comment: If you're invoking the `DataArea` function like this: `$.DataArea();`, then `this` in that function will be the global `jQuery` function, so your `extend` items and the `init` function are being added as properties to the jQuery function instance. I don't imagine that's what you actually want. Can you show `DataArea` in use? Were you instead trying to create a plugin?

Comment: @patrick thanks for looking, nothing I do seems to make it work and it's not throwing any errors, I've edited the answer to show you it in use

Comment: I'm not sure that's true, @patrick.  The .each function should scope 'this' to the element being iterated, regardless of what 'this' is in the calling scope.

Comment: @Matt: Yes, but I was talking about the calling context of `$.DataArea` itself. In the original question, there was no indication that `new` was being used, and as such a call like `$.DataArea()` would make `this` in the `DataArea` function refer to the `jQuery` function instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go back to using `this` instead of `i`, and use the [`find()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method  instead of the [`children()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method.

```
this.init = function() {

      //------------v
    this.container.find('.jobArea .bar, .jobArea .marker').each(function(i) {
        $(this).bind("selectstart", _preventDefault);
    });

};
```

This is necessary becuase `.bar` and `.marker` are not direct descendants of `container`.

Answer (score 0):

The second variable passed to the `.each()` callback is the actual element. You should be able to re-write it like so:

```
this.container.children('.jobArea .bar, .jobArea .marker').each(function(i,e) {
    $(e).bind("selectstart", _preventDefault);
});
```

**Edit**
I think it's also worth mentioning that the `selectstart` event is not supported in all browsers which may actually be the problem.